# Formatting textfield on focus lost based on condition

Tags: java, swing, formatting, jformattedtextfield

Here is what I need: A textfield in which user can enter either:

1234567890 or 11234567890

and it needs to be formatted accordingly as

123-456-7890 or 1 123-456-7890

Essentially a phone number with or without country code. So far I have a code that does the following:

```
if (isPhone && !getText().equals(BLANK_STRING)) {
        int phoneLength = getText().replaceAll("[^0-9]", "").length();
        String text = getText().replaceAll("[^0-9]", "");
//We call the method to format the entered text after we left the field
        setPhoneFormatMask(phoneLength, text); 
}
```

---

```
private void setPhoneFormatMask(int length, String text) {
    System.out.println("length = " + length);
    System.out.println("text = " + text);
    switch (length) {
        case 10:
            try {
                System.out.println("Setting mask");
                numberMaskFormat.setMask("###-###-####");
            } catch (ParseException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(WWNumericFormattedTextField.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
            break;
        case 11:
            try {
                System.out.println("setting mask 2");
                numberMaskFormat.setMask("# ###-###-####");
            } catch (ParseException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(WWNumericFormattedTextField.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
            break;
    }
    setFormatter(numberMaskFormat);
    System.out.println("n:" + numberMaskFormat.getMask());
    setText(text);
}

@Override
public void focusGained(FocusEvent e) {
    if (isPhone) {
        try {
            numberMaskFormat.setMask("**************");
        } catch (ParseException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(WWFormattedTextField.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        setFormatter(numberMaskFormat);
    }
}
```

Console output:

```
//Application launched
focus gained
n2:**************
//I entered 9051234567 and tabbed out
Focus lost
length = 10
text = 9051234657
Setting mask
n:###-###-####
Formatted text =    -   -    
//Tabbed back in
focus gained
n2:**************
//Entered 19051234567 and tabbed out
Focus lost
length = 11
text = 19051234567
setting mask 2
n:# ###-###-####
Formatted text =
```

I need advise/help/guidance on how to format the text in the JFormattedTextField after the focus is lost and the formatting varies based on how many digits were entered.

Comment: Then when your formatted text field again gain focus: will it needs to change it's text format form `123-456-7890` to `1234567890` ? wired option requirement!!

Comment: Anyway take a look to the answer. see if it helps to meet your requirement

Answer (score 0):

**First**, use mask: `#` for any valid number, uses Character.isDigit because `*` works for any character.

**Second**, use `DefaultFormatterFactory` while setting formatter to `JFormattedTextFeild`:

```
    ftf.setFormatterFactory(new DefaultFormatterFactory(
                                                new MaskFormatter("######")));
```

`ftf` is a `JFormattedTextFeild`. Try to assign an `input verifier` to the `formatted text field` to do checking and verify text on focus lose event. The [`InputVarifier`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/InputVerifier.html) will call a function `boolean shouldYieldFocus(JComponent input)` on focus lose event to check whither it should lose the focus. I have written a sample example one for you, you can easily adopt it to fit your need:

```
 class myInputVarifier extends InputVerifier
{
  public boolean maskChanged = false;
  MaskFormatter maskFormatter ;
  JFormattedTextField ftf;
  @Override
  public boolean verify(JComponent input) {
    if (input instanceof JFormattedTextField) {
             ftf = (JFormattedTextField)input;
             maskFormatter = (MaskFormatter) ftf.getFormatter();
             ;
             if(!isValid()) return false; 
                           // check with mask ###### first, if valid change the mask
                           // to # ##-### and reset the text 

             if(!maskChanged)
             {
               try {
                    String text = ftf.getText();  
                           // get the text formatted as ###### = 112123
                     maskFormatter.setMask("# ##-###");
                     ftf.setFormatterFactory(
                                           new DefaultFormatterFactory(maskFormatter));
                     ftf.setText(text);
                          //resetting the text will be formatted as # ##-### = 1 12-123
                     maskChanged = true;
               } catch (ParseException ex) {
                   }

               return isValid();
             }


          }
          return true;
  }

  public boolean isValid()
  {
        try {
           maskFormatter.stringToValue(ftf.getText());
           return true;
         } catch (ParseException pe) {
             return false;
           }
   }

  @Override
  public boolean shouldYieldFocus(JComponent input) {
    return verify(input);
  }
}
```